# Working with large arrays - OutOfRam

Tags: delphi

I have an algorithm where I create two bi-dimensional arrays like this:

```
  TYPE
   TPtrMatrixLine = array of byte;
   TCurMatrixLine = array of integer;
   TPtrMatrix     = array of TPtrMatrixLine;                                    
   TCurMatrix     = array of TCurMatrixLine;  


  function x
  var  
     PtrsMX: TPtrMatrix;
     CurMx : TCurMatrix;         
  begin 
   { Try to allocate RAM }
   SetLength(PtrsMX, RowNr+1, ColNr+1);                              
   SetLength(CurMx , RowNr+1, ColNr+1);
   for all rows do 
    for all cols do 
     FillMatrixWithData; <------- CPU intensive task. It could take up to 10-20 min
  end;
```

The two matrices have always the same dimension.
Usually there are only 2000 lines and 2000 columns in the matrix but sometimes it can go as high as 25000x6000 so for both matrices I need something like 146.5 + 586.2 = 732.8MB of RAM.
The problem is that the two blocks need to be contiguous so in most cases, even if 500-600MB of free RAM doesn't seem much on a modern computer, I run out of RAM.

The algorithm fills the cells of the array with data based on the neighbors of that cell. The operations are just additions and subtractions.

The TCurMatrixLine is the one that takes a lot or RAM since it uses integers to store data. Unfortunately, values stored may have sign so I cannot use Word instead of integers. SmallInt is too small (my values are bigger than SmallInt, but smaller than Word). I hope that if there is any other way to implement this, it needs not to add a lot of overhead, since processing a matrix with so many lines/column already takes a lot of time. In other words I hope that decreasing memory requirements will not increase processing time.

Any idea how to decrease the memory requirements?
[I use Delphi 7]

---

**Update**
Somebody suggested that each row of my array should be an independent uni-dimensional array.
I create as many rows (arrays) as I need and store them in TList. Sound very good. Obviously there will be no problem allocation such small memory blocks. But I am afraid it will have a gigantic impact on speed. I use now

```
TCurMatrixLine = array of integer;                                   
TCurMatrix     = array of TCurMatrixLine;
```

because it is faster than `TCurMatrix= array of array of integer` (because of the way data is placed in memory). So, breaking the array in independent lines may affect the speed.

Comment: A `SHORT` or `Smallint` is a signed 16-bit integer. That's the same size with a `WORD`.

Comment: How many null-entries will there be in the matrices? For sparse matrices (many entries with a default value) a list representation might be more compact.

Comment: As explained, SmallInt is too small (my values are bigger than SmallInt, but smaller than Word).

Comment: IMO, you really need to determine whether this is a candidate for sparse matricies or not, before choosing a path forward.  I would go with this unless you can't.

Comment: Actually, the explanation you've given here doesn't quite up. In Delphi, `array of array of T` already is a ragged matrix. So, each row `CurMx[row]` is itself a distinct block of memory. So, even assuming that your max dimension is 25,000, this only results in a requirement to find 100KB blocks of address space. I suspect what is actually happening is that you are allocating and reallocating during the lifetime of the process and so are fragmenting your address space. Still, a sub-block allocator as I suggest will help but make sure your sub-blocks are always the same size!

Comment: > I suspect what is actually happening is that you are allocating and reallocating - - - Yes. I call this function even 5-50 times during app life time.

Comment: > do you have different values for RowNr ColNr - - - You mean inside of the function? Inside of my x function, the RowNr/ColNr are fix. But I call the function multiple times and I each time, these values may be different.

Comment: @Altar OK, memory fragmentation explains the symptoms and I think you know the solution now!

Comment: Are you sure about your update? You seem to compare `TCurMatrix= array of TCurMatrixLine` with `TCurMatrix= array of array of TCurMatrixLine`. That doesn't seem right, the latter is 3 dimensional. Perhaps you meant `array of array of Integer` but if so then you should be advised that is equivalent to `TCurMatrix= array of TCurMatrixLine` and performs the same. Dynamic arrays are 1 dimensional. Their elements may be dynamic arrays which gives the apperance of a 2D structure but it's really a ragged matrix rather than a pure matrix structure.

Comment: @Altar: You say that your values are bigger than SmallInt and smaller than (the non-existing) signed Word.  Can you tell exactly what range we are talking about?

Comment: >Can you tell exactly what range we are talking about? - - - The values are under the 65355 threshold (both plus and minus). Of course signed Word does not exist. I already stated that "Unfortunately, values stored may have sign so I cannot use Word".    Probably an idea that I had (to move data from negative range into the positive range) was still lingering in my mind.

Comment: >Perhaps you meant array of array of Integer - - - Yah. Sorry. I fixed that already. I have made some tests and it is faster that way because when you are accessing the array in a loop you don't have to recalculate the address of the line.

Comment: but those declarations are equivalent to each other. The object code and memory layout produced will be identical.

Comment: @Altar: OK, just had to ask...  If you only needed the range `-10000..50000`, Delphi would align _this_ custom subrange type into a 4byte datatype, but if you defined the custom subrange as `0..60000`, Delphi would align _that_ into 2byte.  The `-65536..65535`-range only needs 17 bits, but Delphi aligns this into 4byte...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion of using a signed 2 byte integer will greatly aid you.

Another useful tactic is to mark your exe as being `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` by adding `{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}` to your .dpr file. This will only help if you are running on 64 bit Windows and will increase your address space from 2GB to 4GB.

It may not work on Delphi 7 (I seem to recall you are using D7) and you must be using FastMM since the old Borland memory manager isn't compatible with large address space. If `$SetPEFlags` isn't available you can still mark the exe with `EDITBIN`.

If you still encounter difficulties then yet another trick is to do allocate smaller sub-blocks of memory and use a wrapper class to handle mapping indices to the appropriate sub-block and offset within. You can use a default index property to make this transparent to the calling code.

Naturally a block allocated approach like this does incur some processing overhead but it's your best bet if you are having troubles with getting contiguous blocks.

Comment: Splitting the big array in smaller parts was also one of my ideas. I will have to try it and see if it worth it (if it adds too much overhead).

Comment: Splitting into sub-blocks will definitely do the trick. Make a nice wrapper to abstract the implementation details, so that you can continue to think of the matrix as originally envisioned.

Comment: As explained, SmallInt is too small (my values are bigger than SmallInt, but smaller than Word).

Comment: @Altar with D2009 generics I now have a class named `TBlockAllocatedList<T>` which can hold anything and offers up the traditional `Count` and `Items[]` properties that you would expect. It really does make a huge difference. My app uses a lot of large arrays and without this strategy it would not be viable in 32 bit address space. This is one of the often unspoken problems with 32 bit address space. It's not necessarily that you need >4GB, you often die long before you get there because of the issue you raise.

Comment: @Altar You could use a packed bit set for the signs! So each item would consume 17 bits rather than 32 as at present. I think sub-allocation is worth trying first though.

Comment: @Altar Sorry, I hadn't fully hauled in that Smallint was too small.

Comment: @David - "You could use a packed bit set for the signs" - you mean that I should keep the sign in a separate matrix?

Comment: @Altar yes indeed. The array would need to be an array of byte and each element would hold the sign of 8 items in your Word array. I'd use a block allocated list though!

Comment: Hi David. I changed a bit the constants I use in the algorithm and now the values stored in the cells are in the SmallInt range. I will have to make lots of tests with real input data, because I think in some (rare) scenarios the values might go out of range (of SmallInt). But it is a trade of I am willing to make. The program was crashing anyway before this change when trying to allocate memory. Now, with this change it can handle bigger input sets! Thanks.

Comment: @Altar Do you understand my comment that `TCurMatrix= array of TCurMatrixLine` is identical to `TCurMatrix= array of array of Integer`?

Answer (score 2):

If the absolute values of elements of CurMx fits word then you can store it in word and use another array of boolean for its sign. It reduces 1 byte for each element.

Comment: This is a rather poor solution. A signed 2 byte integer would get the job done much more effectively.

Comment: @David Heffernan, Altar said it doesn't fit SmallInt(which is 2 byte signed integer)

Comment: Thanks Azad - starting from your idea, I have changed some constants in my code so now the data stored in the matrix does not go beyond the SmallInt boundaries. I have to test if the new constant values are working as good as the old ones. If YES, then I have decreased the memory requirements to almost half.

Comment: @Altar Azad's suggestion was rather different. What you have implemented now is actually what @Sertac suggested in the first comment to your Q!

Comment: @David - Actually I started from your and Azad idea. You both suggested to decrease the size of my cell. And I did. Maybe not the way you suggested, but I got positive results! Now I use SmallInt instead of Integer. +1 to both (and I marked your answer as solution).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to manually allocate the data structure on the heap?
...and measured how this will affect the memory usage and the performance?

Using the heap might actually increase speed and reduce the memory usage, because you can avoid the whole array to be copied from one memory segment to another memory segment.  (Eg. if your `FillMatrixWithData` are declared with a non-const open array parameter).

Comment: SetLength allocates on the heap, so I don't think this is it.

Comment: Delphi arrays declared as `array of Type` w/o bounds `[]` are automagically managed on the heap.

Comment: @David, @Viktor: Oh yes, of course...  But the array might still be reallocated during its lifetime when using this approach.  My suggestion is to handle the memory management with `^'s` and `@'s`.

Comment: @Jørn It only gets reallocated when you reallocate it. Using pointers doesn't help - it's equivalent to dynamic arrays.

Comment: So, I will have no success by declaring the vars outside my function?

Comment: @Altar:  No.  If you you don't pass the array as a parameter to another function nor reallocates the size of the array in the function, then it doesn't matter...

Comment: Oh... now you understand what you mean with "because you can avoid the whole array to be copied from one memory segment to another". Got it.